# Getting NaN when easing out of a movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem. I have made movement with friction and ease out code runs perfectly the first time it runs but doesn't run properly after the first run. I have added trace commands to debug and after the first time it runs the **vx** value returns NaN.

leftPressed is a Boolean

righPressed is a boolean

vx is the x velocity

friction is the speed of the ease out

```
    public var vy:Number = 30;
    public var vyInitial:Number;//This is initialised later
    public var gravity:Number = 2.0;
    public var vx:Number = 0.4;
    public var vxInitial:Number;//This is initialised later
    public var friction:Number = 0.4;
```

Here is the code used: Including the jumping ease code that works fine.

```
        if (leftPressed)
        {
            if (vx == 0)
            {
                vx = vxInitial;
            }
            char.x -=  vx;
            lastMove = "Left";
        }
        else if (rightPressed)
        {
            if (vx == 0)
            {
                vx = vxInitial;
            }
            char.x +=  vx;
            lastMove = "Right";
        }
        else if (rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)
        {
            if (lastMove == "Right" && rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)
            {
                vx -=  friction;
                trace(vx);
                if (vx < 0)
                {
                    lastMove = "No Move";
                    trace("lastMove Right");
                    vx = 0;
                }
                else if (vx > 0)
                {
                    trace("moving left");
                    char.x +=  vx;
                }
            }
            else if (lastMove == "Left" && rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false)
            {
                vx -=  friction;
                trace(vx);
                if (vx < 0)
                {
                    lastMove = "No Move";
                    trace("lastMove Left");
                    vx = 0;
                }
                else if (vx > 0)
                {
                    trace("moving LEft");
                    char.x -=  vx;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you add some code, about the declaration of vx, and using it as a local variable or global

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code regarding `vx`... Maybe the problem is that somewhere else you are saying `vx = null`?

Comment: Did you initialize `vxInitial` before assigning its value to `vx`? Try `public var vxInitial:Number=0`;//This is initialised later` and the same for vyInitial.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this line:

```
if (vx == 0)
{
    vx = vxInitial;
}
```

Would not get called the first time, since vx is initially equal to 0.4 (not zero).  During the first run vx is set to zero though:

```
if (vx < 0)
{
     lastMove = "No Move";
     trace("lastMove Right");
     vx = 0;
}
```

So the next time it is run vx is set to the value of vxInitial, which appears to have no value:

```
public var vxInitial:Number;//This is initialised later (Is it?)
```

Set vxInitial and it shouldn't error.